# Networking lobby player image not working on host and other clients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I am trying to create a lobby for my game. I need to set a profile image for every player, but I can't send to texture from each player profile image to the server

anny sugestions?

I have tried using Command like this

```
    [Command]
    public void CmdPlayerProfile(byte[] test)
    {
        myBites.Add(test);
        profileImagebyte = test;
    }
```

The command function gets called in the OnClientEnterLobby

I am using a extra class to manage the SyncList

```
  public class LobbyPlayerImage : NetworkBehaviour
{
public class SyncListByte : SyncList<byte[]>
{
    protected override byte[] DeserializeItem(NetworkReader reader)
    {
        return reader.ReadBytesAndSize();
    }

    protected override void SerializeItem(NetworkWriter writer, byte[] item)
    {
   //     writer.Write(item, Buffer.ByteLength(item));
        writer.WriteBytesFull(item);
      //  writer.WriteBytesAndSize(item, Buffer.ByteLength(item));

    }
}
public SyncListByte myBites = new SyncListByte();
```

}

When I use this, I get an error saying my `byte[]` is to big

Comment: Can you attach code samples of your attempts?

Comment: @ThePyzhov yeah sure

Comment: I don't get it, why are u doing the deserialize stuff? images are stored somewhere? I will try different approach, like when you want to change the "color team" on the Network Lobby prefab.

Comment: @Lotan I just looked at other examples but they don't seem to work. The images are comming from a previous scene

Comment: @Lotan i tried to do it the same like the color team but the byte[] is to large, anny suggestion?

Comment: @MickeyEvers the images are from a "default set" of images? or every user can upload their own images? Those images are stored in any server that you got control on it?

Comment: @Lotan they are stored on a server. Every player has a different imgae

Comment: @MickeyEvers hmmm...just throwing ideas out there, maybe loading with bundles?

Comment: @Lotan not working either, other sugestions?